# iOS Safari show keyboard with comma instead of period

Tags: ios, html, safari

How do we make iOS keyboard (in Safari) show a comma instead of a period?

When the user taps on the input field, they get a keyboard with a period on the right.

[image: iOS keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

It's by setting `input type="text"`, rather than `type="email"` which I previously had!